# How does one establish multiple IO streams between a client and server?

Tags: java, sockets, io

I'm creating a client/server pair in Java that, for now, only supports interlaced text communication via PrintWriters and BufferedReaders wrapped around both server and client's IO streams.

I would like to implement a function that uses Image[Input/Output]Stream to send a BufferedImage from the server to the client at a set interval.

The problem is that I want the BufferedImages to be sent/received in separate threads so that the client/server can still send/receive text commands.

Can I create multiple streams or sockets? If so, is that the best way?

Comment: You can create multiple sockets, just open additional ones the same way as you made your first one (you can't have multiple sockets open to the same ip/port combination however so pick a different port).

Comment: Thanks. I thought I might have to go in that direction. Is there no way to do it with only 1 port? I may want to implement other functions that should run simultaneously... Is it normal for applications to open so many ports?

Comment: It's quite normal for applications to open many ports, but it's obviously nicer for end users if you stick with one. The only other option is multiplexing data over your single socket as described by Jarrod.

Comment: Don't use PrintWriter over the network. It swallows exceptions you need to know about. In this case you could use BufferedWriter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to accomplish this with a single socket is multiplexing the individual streams over a single bytestream connected to the socket, a good implementation of this is [BEEP](http://beepcore.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure you can create as many threads and sockets as you need. Just be careful: do not forget to close sockets and keep process of threads creation under control: to many threads do not improve your performance and may even cause your system to halt.

Probably you should use thread pool. But it depends on your application. Take a look on `java.util.concurrency` package.

If you have more specific questions do not hesitate to ask them.

Answer (score 0):

A multiplexing stream should maintain multiple buffers.

A reader should be given it's own buffer by the multiplexing stream. The multiplexing stream should grow every buffer during a write operation, and shrink the desired buffer during a read operation.

A single rewind buffer is harder to manage, since the readers need to be stateful, but is generally more scalable, if not performant.

The specific connection protocol used is an implementation detail. Network sockets are just buffers, and can be used to implement a multiplexing stream. The network becomes the bottleneck in this case.