# Multiple Object Streams Over a Single Socket

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am writing a program that requires large data like images (and eventually maybe audio streams or something, though that isn't an immediate goal), as well as small instructions to be send Host -> Client. Currently, I can write this as a plain TCP client-server application. However, this does mean that whenever an image is being sent, no other data will be being transferred, including fairly important small instructions which could be being sent very quickly. I could fix this by creating multiple sockets between the server and each client, but I would really rather keep things to one socket (and thus one port being used). Is there a protocol or something that I can use to send multiple streams of data concurrently (or at least somehow interweaved maybe?)? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796179/how-does-one-establish-multiple-io-streams-between-a-client-and-server) looks similar to yours.

Comment: Using extra sockets will work immediately. Writing your own interlacing protocol is a major risk and time cost. Do it the easy way.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend that you separate the two, this is a practice used by many other protocols (e.g. [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol)).

If you really want to combine them you can but I don't know of any standard tool to do so.  Keep in mind that you will need some way of knowing on the client side which byte came from which stream.  You will likely need to invent some kind of escape sequence to send in the data stream to indicate to the client that control instructions are coming.  Of course, that escape sequence could occur naturally in your data so you would need to encode your data appropriately as well.

EDIT: Another approach would be to frame your data.  Send a DATA START command and then 1024 bytes of your data and then any other commands and then a DATA CONTINUE command and then the next 1024 bytes and then a DATA END command when you're done (DATA START/CONTINUE/END are of course made up commands in some protocol you invent).

It would be an interesting problem to tackle if you have the time and are interested in the learning but if you are in any kind of hurry this will likely be a slower approach than using multiple sockets.  You can always send the control message first to the client and have the client open the data connection to your server.  This will allow you to only have to open one port on the client side and one on the server side and can often simplify firewall concerns.